# Vertx JDBCClient with HttpVerticle timing out

Tags: jdbc, vert.x

I need some help in troubleshooting one of my vertx service. I have a db verticle that uses JDBCClient. My code was working fine until recently and now it started giving timeout exception. The db client is taking too much time to return the results and by the time it returns the results, the httpverticle is timing out.

When I query the database outside vertx, it returns result in 10 milliseconds, so I believe the database is working fine. The verticle fails immediately after restart as well. So it does not seems to be because of overload.

My code:

```
public class TestDbVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("TestDbVerticle");

    private JDBCClient dbClient;

    @Override
    public void start(Future < Void > startFuture) throws Exception {
        logger.trace("start - Starting TestDbVerticle...");

        JsonObject config = new JsonObject();
        config.put("url", config().getString("url"));
        config.put("driver_class", config().getString("driver_class"));
        config.put("max_pool_size", config().getInteger("max_pool_size"));
        config.put("min_pool_size", config().getInteger("min_pool_size"));
        config.put("max_statements", config().getInteger("max_statements"));

        dbClient = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, config, "jdbc/test");

        dbClient.getConnection(ar - > {
            if (ar.failed()) {
                logger.error("start- Could not open a database connection", ar.cause());
                startFuture.fail(ar.cause());
            } else {
                logger.trace("start- DB Vertcle connected to db successfully.");

                vertx.eventBus().consumer(config().getString("test.queue.address"), this::onMessage);
                startFuture.complete();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onMessage(Message < JsonObject > message) {
        if (!message.headers().contains("action")) {
            logger.error("No action header specified for message with headers {} and body {}", message.headers(),
                message.body().encodePrettily());
            message.fail(100, "No action header specified");
            return;
        }
        String action = message.headers().get("action");

        switch (action) {
            case "find_by_id":
                findById(message);
                break;

            default:
                message.fail(101, "Bad action: " + action);
        }
    }

    private void findById(Message < JsonObject > message) {
        try {
            JsonObject request = message.body();

            Long id = Long.parseLong(request.getString("id").trim());

            JsonArray params = new JsonArray().add(id);

            final long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            String query = "SELECT * from test WHERE test_id =? ORDER BY created_date DESC;";
            logger.debug("findById - params [" + params + "}. query [" + query + "]");

            dbClient.queryWithParams(query, params, result - > {
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long totalTime = currentTime - time;
                logger.debug("findById - Total time taken to execute query [" + totalTime + "]");

                if (result.succeeded()) {
                    logger.debug("findById - Query exection successed with numrows [" + result.result().getNumRows() + "]");
                    if (result.result().getNumRows() > 0) {
                        message.reply(result.result().getRows().get(0).toString());
                    } else {
                        message.reply(result.result().getRows().toString());
                    }

                } else {
                    logger.error("findById - Failed getting data", result.cause());

                    JsonObject out = new JsonObject();
                    out.put("error_code", 10);
                    out.put("status", "Fail");

                    message.reply(out);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("findById - Failed getting data by id failed", e);

            JsonObject out = new JsonObject();
            out.put("error_code", 20);
            out.put("status", "GenericException");

            message.reply(out);
        }
    }
}
```

The start method get executed without any problem. Log prints "start- DB Vertcle connected to db successfully.". The calls from http verticle reaches the onMessage and findById method. Query on line number 74 getting printed and then the http verticle errors out as it waited for 30000 milliseconds. The time it took to execute the dbClient.queryWithParams method was more than a minute. This was working fine in until recently.

I changed the connection pool to HikariCP and it made no differences.

Can someone please help to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Since it worked fine with same code before and nothing changes when using another connection pool, I'd look into possible networking problems.

Comment: I have another service working fine in the same system without any issues. So I don't think its network problems